# Computer analysis of ESL learners' mistakes

Tags: english, computational-linguistics

This is a very broad question; I'm trying to get a sense of the current state of this subfield of NLP and what relevant resources may already exist, so even tangential answers will be welcome.

To what extent can computers currently identify errors produced by learners of English (or any other language), whether in speaking or writing?

Imagine that the ideal is a program that could converse with you, an ESL learner, and identify errors of various types -- grammar, vocabulary, pronunciation etc. I assume nothing approaching this currently exists (right?), but which of the building blocks of such a program exist in even partial form?

For example, a useful answer might be "Here's a Python library that can identify subject-verb agreement errors in an English text". Another type of useful answer would be "Here's a corpus of conversational English produced by ESL learners of a certain level". Basically I'm looking for pointers to any parts of this puzzle that may already have been solved to some extent.

Comment: Not very well at all, unless you have a very small and precisely-determined list of "errors" to look for. What counts as an error varies vastly from learner to learner and teacher to teacher. Take a look at the questions in https://english.stackexchange.com/ or https://ell.stackexchange.com/ to see the outright nonsense ESL students are faced with worldwide.

Comment: @jlawler Sure, and that's unfortunately true not just for ESL but also for assessment of native speakers' English (e.g. on the SAT/ACT). To be clear, I'm asking about real errors of the type no native speaker would produce, not violations of zombie rules.

Comment: There is *a lot* of research going on in this area. One of my colleagues used to work with texts produced by bilingual children and developed annotation schemes for different types of errors (which is really hard because you'll often have multiple options to correct an error) so what I know is mostly anecdotal in nature, but this article might be worth a read for an overview and some resources: [Ng et al., 2014, The CoNLL-2014 Shared Task on Grammatical Error Correction](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W14-1701)